# Not able to connect the Google Cloud Load Balancer generated using ingress-nginx on Browser after adding the LB IP in my windows hosts file

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Kubernetes in GCE-GKE, I was trying to build and deploy the nodeJS app in GCE-GKE cluster using the skaffold.Yaml. I can see image got build and also deployed withoutr any issue but when I tried to access GET the index.ts file on browser, I can't. I really don't understand what might have gone wrong or I may have missed something at LB or ingress-nginx.

Below id the skaffold.yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  # local:
  #   push: false
  googleCloudBuild:
    projectId: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  artifacts:
    - image: us.gcr.io/xxxxxxxxxxx/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

Below is ingress-srv.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

Below is auth-depl.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: us.gcr.io/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Below is package.json

```
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.44"
  }
}
```

Below is index.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import { json } from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
app.use(json());
// /api/users/currentuser
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Great');
  console.log('listening on port 3000!!!!!');
});
```

Below is docker file

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Which tools you use to manage domain configuraion?

Step 1: As far as i know, after you init nginx on your k8s cluster, you need add a DNS record to map a domain (or subdomain) in your domain (ticketing.dev) to external IP or external DNS of your k8s cluster which nginx have regenerated for you (i use an A record normally).

Step 2: After that, when you have deployed your application, you need to set the domain of your app (domain name you specify in your ingress yaml file) is a CNAME record of the above (A) record.

You can verify your domain verify cation by use `nslookup` command.
If you do not use proxy for your domain, both of above domain (A and CNAME record) will be resolve to the same your externall IP of your k8s cluster.

The purpose of 2 above steps is that you let the DNS server know where (which IP) to resolve when the DNS server get a req ask about any your subdomain (domain). That why you can use `nslookup` command to verify your configuration.

Below is the tools i have used to manage DNS of our domain: 
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9607/2210/how-to-set-up-dns-records-for-your-domain-in-cloudflare-account
[example](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9607/2210/how-to-set-up-dns-records-for-your-domain-in-cloudflare-account)